# Component Identification

Tags: components

Can anyone identify the black IC component for me please?
I have tried to find it I have no idea what it is, it is on the PCB for a piezo.

[image]

[Full Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF4Sa.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

It is a [KTC3875 NPN Transistor](http://www.weitron.com.tw/PDF/KTC3875.pdf) in a SOT-23 package.

Comment: @JonnyFlowers why did you un-select this as the answer? I answered your question and did it 1 minute after you asked it.

Comment: I remember the near identical other answer getting accepted on this question - I had given you a +1 right then, to counter the unfairness :-)