# can't read&store in global variable in function OR can, but get error reading ds18b20 sensor

Tags: avr, atmega, floating-point, codevision

I'm using Atmega8 with CVAVR 2.05.0 and trying to slightly modify the way ds18b20 library works. I want to store temperatures from sensors in global array and start conversion for all sensors at one time - so i can avoid useless delays and do something usefull.
For now in "Project Configure - C Compiler -Code Generation - (s)printf Features" are set to "float,width,precision".
[image: float configured]

I found a problem (tested it in Proteus 7.7 SP2 and on real atmega8) - if i call tempature reading in function inside printf like this:

```
    printf("t%i read=%.4f \n\r", i, ds18b20_read_temperature(&rom_code_ds18b20[i][0]));
```

it works fine, except it can't read global variable inside function. But if before that print i put any assigment to global float array like this:

```
    temperatures[i] = i + 0.275;
    printf("t%i read=%.4f \n\r", i, ds18b20_read_temperature(&rom_code_ds18b20[i][0]));
```

i start getting errors (-9999) for every read for 2nd and 3rd sensor, no matter what is in asigment - if it is assigment to **global** varible. **But** it starts reading from global array right values.

Firs I tried to read global float array in main - it works fine. Then i tried to do same temperature reading in main - again, inside printf it works fine, but if i try assign result of reading to local variable *t1* and then printf those *t1* - i get zero.

Here is example for "good" output (no assign before prints, but no global variable read in function):
[image]

Here is example for "bad" output (put assign before prints, global variable starts reading normally, but 2&3 sensors are lost (see those -9999?) ):
[image]

Where is the problem?
Or there is something i should know about defining or using arrays and/or in functions?

About global variable i found only [about problems inside interrupts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53218/pic-global-variable-not-modified-inside-interrupt-handler), there was recomended to use volatile. Tried volatile - no effect. Also tried pointers (i'm not familiar with them, but with help of friend...)  - the same thing - no reading global in function and "loosing sensor readings".

Also after compiling project i get warnings:

> Warning: C:...\my_reading_ds18b20\my_reading_ds18b20.c(261): array index is out of range
>   Warning: C:...\my_reading_ds18b20\my_reading_ds18b20.c(263): array index is out of range
>   Warning: C:...\my_reading_ds18b20\my_reading_ds18b20.c(265): array index is out of range

I checked that variable *number_of_sensors*=3 (with printf), so i don't understand why i get this warning. Maybe because this varible is set with preprocessor?

Here is my **.c file**: watch for **lines 80, 251, 252**

https://app.box.com/s/8e3no26kfetoutiaqt6vn1rvsxq7wo2n

(with comments and "debug" printf. if anything isn't clear - ask me)

And here (if needed) **.prj file**:
https://app.box.com/s/52oo40bvo0fx02dshmjaw0nsv1mlywco

**I draw your attention that it is NOT about reading dsb18b20** - those function is from library and works well, but about problems got from global float variable. I really need to store those values for later use!

UPDATE1: Seems the problem in everything except t1..t4 was in setting variable *number of sensors*, because if change initializng array *float temperatures[number_of_sensors]* to *float temperatures[4]* all previous problems are gone. So it seems i can't get number of sensors defined by way i used. Is there any other way except automatically change number of sensors depending on used options?

Comment: From those warning messages, it appears there is a problem with the first index of the rom_code_ds18b20[i][0] array - looks like "number_of_sensors" is not getting set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From those warning messages, it appears there is a problem with the first index of the rom_code_ds18b20[i][0] array - looks like "number_of_sensors" is not getting set correctly.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you! Replacing number_of_sensors with 4 makes everything work well. Except the t1 t2 t3 t4 - still getting zero.